# i want particular checkbox to get tick when text is written in textbox? which method or event is used for this?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have 7 textbox  and 7 corresponding checkbox if user input in any of the text box  its particular checkbox should get tick and selected textboxes text will be posted for query by click of a  Search button 
how to do it..via C#.net? which method  or event should i use to  check for this condition. Is i have to do it on page_load event with viewstate?
Suggest me what to do thanks in advance...

Searching Filters
                    
                    
                        
                             
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        Title
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Description
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Category
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                        *
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Location 
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Sources
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Keywords
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Date From
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                
                                                
                                                    
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                    
                                                
                                                
                                                    *
                                                    *
                                                
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                        Date Upto 
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
                                                
                                                
                                                    
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                    
                                                
                                                
                                                    *
                                                    *
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to detect the input text change, you can do that with the help of [JQuery](http://jquery.com). u should look at http://api.jquery.com/change/ here for .change() method for text inputs.

**EDIT :**

here is an on-the-fly example;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Test</title>
</head>
<body>

Name : <input type="text" id="txtName" /> <input type="checkbox" id="chxName" /><br/><br/>
Surname : <input type="text" id="txtSurname" /> <input type="checkbox" id="chxSurname" /><br/><br/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#txtName').change(function(){

      var poo = $(this).val();
      var foo = $('#chxName');
      if(poo == 'bar'){
        if(!foo.is(':checked')) {
          foo.attr('checked','checked');
        }
      } else {
        if(foo.is(':checked')) {
          foo.removeAttr('checked');
        }
      }

    });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

run this example and enter 'bar' inside the first textbox. u will see the first checkbox has been ticked. then enter another word except 'bar'. u will see the first checkbox has been unticked.

Also you can consider some of the other jQuery events like keyup, keydown or keypress

Comment: @Aishna you cannot detect client moves without postback with c#. you need to use javascript to do that. but you can call a c# method from client side code. here is an example : http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-forms---calling-web-service-page-methods-using-jquery